# How to extract a number of images from one picture in Python and save them as separate files

Tags: python, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have a picture containing different species of coral. I want to extract every image of coral contained in this picture and save them as separate .jpg or .png files. (whichever works).
[Here is the original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABV7U.jpg)

I have done image processing and  gotten the contours of the different species of coral using the following code.

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#blur image to reduce the noise in the image while thresholding. 
#This smoothens the sharp edges in the image.
blur = cv2.blur(gray, (10,10))

#Apply thresholding to the image
#Tis changes the pixels of the image to make easier to analyse
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

#find the contours in the image
#Selecting areas of interest 
contours, heirarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#draw the obtained contour lines(or the set of coordinates forming a line) on the original image
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 5)
```

[Here is the final image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfX24.jpg)

Now I need to find a code that will loop over every species (object in the picture), extract and save them as separate files. I don't know how to do this. I have done some research and most of them can only extract one object from a picture,
But I need to loop over every object in the picture, extract the pixels and save them as separate files.

Please help me if you can.

Any input will be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For storing each contour in separate image file, we may crop the bounding rectangle of each contour and save it as separate image.

Before saving the objects, we may apply few improvements before `findContours`:

- Invert threshold black/white - required because `findContours` finds white contours:

  ```
  ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
  ```
- Replace `cv2.RETR_TREE` with `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` - finding only the outer contours (assume there are no contours inside contours):

  ```
   contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
  ```

---

For saving "objects" to image files, we may do the following:

- Iterate the contours.
- Ignore small contours by computing the area, and verify it's above some threshold.
- Find the bounding rectangle of each contour.
- Crop the bounding rectangle and save it to a PNG image file (name the files by incremental index).

  ```
   idx = 0
   for c in contours:
       area_tresh = 2500
       area = cv2.contourArea(c)
       if area > area_tresh:  # Ignore small contours
           x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)  # Crop the bounding rectangle
           coral_img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w, :]
           output_file_name = 'coral_' + str(idx).zfill(2) + '.png'  # Give image name according index
           cv2.imwrite(output_file_name, coral_img)  # Save the cropped rectangle to PNG image file
           idx += 1
  ```

---

Code sample:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('corals.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#blur image to reduce the noise in the image while thresholding. 
#This smoothness the sharp edges in the image.
blur = cv2.blur(gray, (10,10))

#Apply thresholding to the image
#Tis changes the pixels of the image to make easier to analyses
#ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)  #Invert black/white because findContours finds white contours

#find the contours in the image
#Selecting areas of interest 
#contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)  # Use RETR_EXTERNAL instead of RETR_TREE - assume there is no coral inside a coral

idx = 0
for c in contours:
    area_tresh = 2500
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > area_tresh:  # Ignore small contours
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)  # Crop the bounding rectangle
        coral_img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w, :]
        output_file_name = 'coral_' + str(idx).zfill(2) + '.png'  # Give image name according index
        cv2.imwrite(output_file_name, coral_img)  # Save the cropped rectangle to PNG image file
        idx += 1

#draw the obtained contour lines(or the set of coordinates forming a line) on the original image
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 5)

# Show img and thresh for testing
cv2.imshow('img', cv2.resize(img, (img.shape[1]//2, img.shape[0]//2)))
cv2.imshow('thresh', cv2.resize(thresh, (thresh.shape[1]//2, thresh.shape[0]//2)))

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Here are all the cropped contours with area above 2500:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Few images contains more than one corl, because they are merged to one contour.
Splitting the adjacent corals to is not an easy task.
We may try [Image Segmentation with Watershed Algorithm](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html), but I don't know if it's going to work.